# Mysql is throwing sql error on ORDER BY clause

Tags: mysql, sql

It is absolutely beyond my ideas why the following query is not working:

```
DELETE orig FROM revision AS orig JOIN (
  SELECT id
  FROM revision 
  GROUP BY id 
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) AS joined ON orig.id = joined.id
WHERE orig.id=1 
ORDER BY orig.delta ASC 
LIMIT 1
```

The error is thrown on line 8, so the `ORDER BY` clause. However, I cannot see anything wrong with it (the table `revision` does have a column called `delta`). Moreover, changing `DELETE orig` to `SELECT *` results in a flawlessly working command.

Is it possible that the `delta`-column isn't loaded? Or what is causing this error?

---

**edit**

Ah okay, I didn't know that you cannot use `ORDER BY` with multiple rows on a `DELETE` query.

Well, what I am trying to accomplish is that I delete one row in my table, which has an id that occurs more than once (will be 5 in production) and has the lowest delta of all rows with that id.

I.e. I have two rows in the revision table, both with the same id. I now want to delete that row which has the lowest delta of the two. This should be scalable, so that I delete all rows (with the same id) but one (the one with the highest delta).

Comment: you can't have an order by on a delete statement.

Comment: @Hogan You can in MySQL

Comment: @alex what exactly does this overcomplicated query is trying to do? It seems you want to delete only 1 row so if you explain, it can probably be written simpler.

Comment: Can you add the `SHOW CREATE TABLE revision;` in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are trying to do. It will delete only 1 row only if the `(id,delta)` combination has a unique constraint:

```
DELETE orig 
FROM revision AS orig 
  JOIN 
    ( SELECT MIN(delta) AS delta
      FROM revision 
      WHERE id = 1
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    ) AS joined ON orig.delta = joined.delta
WHERE orig.id = 1 ;
```

---

To delete all rows (with same `id`) except the (say 5) rows with highest `delta`, you can use:

```
DELETE orig 
FROM revision AS orig 
  JOIN 
    ( SELECT delta
      FROM revision 
      WHERE id = 1
      ORDER BY delta DESC
      LIMIT 1 OFFSET 4                         -- select the 5th highest
    ) AS joined ON orig.delta < joined.delta   -- then find the lower than that
WHERE orig.id = 1 ;
```

Comment: Please check whether the `(id,delta)` is unique. What is the primary key of the table?

Comment: I haven't _defined_ a primary key for that table, although `id` is the primary unique key for another table that corresponds to this one (but is unimportant for this query). `(id,delta)` do form the unique key pair for this table. Off topic: I still haven't found a way with MySQL to easily define unique pairs for table consistency, without making any of the pair-parts unique also...

Comment: If I understand this query correctly, it will only ever delete one row (the one with the lowest delta). While this would in principle be sufficient for my use-case, is there any way to delete all but, say, five rows (the ones with the highest delta)?

Comment: Yes, it will delete one row (or more if there are more than one rows with same minimum delta.)

Comment: You can easily define a pair as unique (or primary key): `ALTER TABLE revision ADD UNIQUE INDEX (id,delta);`

Answer (score 2):

You can't use ORDER BY if you have multiple tables in your DELETE statement